# How to make my Unity project deterministic for replays?

Tags: unity, c#, timestep, fixed-timestep, replays

I am working on an arcade-style 2D shmup and recently started implementing a replay system that allows players to view their runs of the game.

I use the technique of recording input each `FixedUpdate()` and rerunning the game as a simulation, reading the saved input each frame and processing it in the core game loop as if it was real-time input from the player.

This requires an extremely deterministic game, and in order to get perfectly synced movement and scoring in the replay, I have had to shift to a paradigm of using exclusively `FixedUpdate()` and `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

I don’t mind this, as I now have 100% reliable replays with no desyncing.

My question concerns whether some of the techniques I used to port my game to the deterministic `FixedUpdate` paradigm are problematic, or if there are better ways to achieve the same effect.

For example, previously I relied heavily on coroutines yielding using `WaitForSeconds()`. This method is underpinned by normal `Update()` loop and so introduced indeterminism into the game leading to desyncs.

To fix it, I still use coroutines, but any time I need to wait, I do it by waiting for *n* number of calls of `FixedUpdate()`. For example,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i ++)
{
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
}
```

This seems to be working just fine to keep the game deterministic, but I wonder if there’s a more straightforward way, or if there are potential issues this type of technique might cause?

In general, are there any other techniques or pitfalls I need to be aware of to keep my game deterministic enough for perfectly synced replays?

Comment: Note that Time.deltaTime automatically returns Time.fixedDeltaTime when accessed during FixedUpdate or collision message handlers, so explicitly changing old deltaTime references might not be required for all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more tinkering, I think I can safely say that using

```
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i ++)
{
    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
}
```

works fine in coroutines to preserve determinism.

That said, there were a few other things I needed to change, and others attempting to move to a FixedUpdate paradigm should be aware of them.

In many of my coroutines, I was sometimes using `yield return null`. This will yield until the next call of `Update()`, which is problematic. I had to convert these lines to yield return new `WaitForFixedUpdate()`.

Finally, I am making heavy use of the [DOTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php) library for tweening. By default, all of the tween update using `Update()`, but I discovered that you can easily set all of them to update during `FixedUpdate()` using

```
    // set Global tween settings
    // NOTE: this is easiest way to make sure all tweens are only
    // updating in fixed update,
    // rather than manually setting tween.SetUpdate(UpdateType.Fixed)
    DOTween.Init();
    DOTween.defaultUpdateType = UpdateType.Fixed;
```